# 5 pin push button switch with LED AC wiring question

Tags: led, switches, ac-dc

Thank you in advance for any help you can give.  This is really my first project like this.  I built a shelf in my house based on this picture.

[image]

and I'm integrating an Eddison bulb lamp into the project for some lighting.  I've decided I want the light to be operated by a switch and I was looking to purchase a small push button that could be screwed into the piping I'm using for the shelving and I could run all the wiring in the pipes to "hide it".

I'm looking to use this  [Switch (for sale on Amazon)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00K77HJWS) which has the following properties, wiring diagram, and an integrated LED to operate the on/off function of the Eddison bulb.
(Switch Properties)
Switch rating:5A/250VAC
 
Switch combination:1NO1NC 
Operation types:Self-locking

[image: Wiring Diagram]
[image]

I did some preliminary digging to find a compatible wiring diagram for the switch but cannot find the voltage/amperage settings for the switch's integrated LED.  Similar switches from the manufacturer with integrated LEDs I have seen have the LED rated at (LED voltage: 12V).  I'm assuming this is 12v DC but i guess i'm only 99.99% certain.

I guess my questions are as follows:

(1) can anyone tell me if the LED is likely 12v DC (is this a stupid question?) and if so, suggest a way to wire in a converter or how I should wire in the LED so that I can fit into the shelf piping and wire it into the same line powering the Edison bulb?  I'm just confused as to how a switch rated for 5a/250v ac would have a 12v (presumably dc) LED on it and how to wire or integrate it into the wiring for the switch itself if I have 120v running through the switch.

(2) is it possible to wire the LED light in such a way that when the Eddison bulb is on, the integrated LED is off and vice versa?

(3) if the amperage coming off the wall is 15/20A as most sockets are, do I need to wire in a resistor to the switch to make sure it's not damaged or will it be okay?

Comment: If the switch doesn't have a data sheet then how could anyone know? 15/20A is the max supply current - any load will take ONLY the current it needs.

Comment: I was hoping maybe someone had experience with this switch or had tried a similar application. Not sure why you voted this down.  I even provided a link to all the data the seller gives in an effort to be complete.  I provided a wiring diagram and asked generally about converting acto dc.  If you read my questions and answer those, the data sheet is not necessary.

Comment: have a look at http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-1728604/wiring-setup-blue-led-22mm-12v-stainless-steel-switch-momentary-push-button.html

Comment: Thanks Jim but what you linked is for a DC application and a 6 pin switch.  I have my wiring diagram above.  the push button switch can handle 250v/5a.  What I'm trying to figure out is, if I wire this into an AC wall lamp as the switch, how should I wire in the LED part of the switch, which is presumably DC) to achieve what I discussed in my questions?(ie. Do I need a converter, is there a small form factor converter that would fit into the tubing of my shelf, is there another way?, etc...)

Comment: You can run the LED from mains through a capacitance/bridge rectifier type circuit something like this http://www.electroschematics.com/3752/transformer-less-power-supply/ but it would mean the LED is live (note: 225k == 0.22uF - must be X rated capacitor at least 400V or more) Personally I don't like having things directly to mains. If you do go that way make sure you're insulation is really good.

Comment: Okay. This makes sense.  If you don't like it live,how would you suggest I get it wired in as an alternative?  Is there a small form factor converter or something I could wire in or that you would suggest?

Comment: I found this, http://amzn.to/1FrOShB , do you think something like this could work?  I could wire it in parallel to the part going to the switch and Edison bulb.  The LED would be on all the time but I can't think of another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to find out if the LED already has a suitable resistor inside the switch for a 12 Vdc supply is to assume that it doesn't.

Add a suitable resistor in series, power the LED & resistor from a 12 Vdc power source, then measure the voltage across the LED terminals in the switch.

If the LED does NOT have a suitable resistor internal to the switch, the voltage across the LED terminals will be anywhere from 1.7 to 3.4 Vdc, depending upon the colour of the LED and the LED will be fairly bright.

If the LED *does* have a resistor inside the switch body, the voltage across the LED terminals will be substantially higher - 6 Vdc or more and the LED will be dimmer than it should be.

Comment: Modify your question with what you find out about the LED inside the switch.  I'll then tell you how I would do the 2nd part of your question.

Comment: Will do.  Also, do you have an recommendations on power supply?  I posted another question here:  [link](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/173674/wiring-ac-switch-with-dc-led)  regarding that.